# deleting entire xml node with datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datagrid

I have the following xml structure:

```
<systemtest>
    <test id="0">
        <name>Test One</name>
    </test>

    <test id="1">
         <name>Test Two</name>
    </test>
</systemtest>
```

The name gets displayed in the 1ste colum of the datagrid, where in the 2nd colum there is a buttoncolumn with delete button.

How exactly can i use xpath and navigate to the current node lets say with test id="0" and delete it (including name)?

Its unclear how i can say to this method what row he has to delete exactly.

```
 XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XMLDoc.Load(XMLFile);
    XPathNavigator nav = XMLDoc.CreateNavigator();
    nav.SelectSingleNode("...."); //??

nav.DeleteSelf(); //will this do the trick?
```

Also the id gets generated in a seperate class where the above method should be.

```
    var node = nav.SelectSingleNode("/testsystem/test[@id='0']");
    node.DeleteSelf();
    XMLDoc.Save(XMLFile);
```

This does delete the first item, but offcourse crashes on the second.
How an i make this into something variable that is bound depending on what button i press in my datagrid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/systemtest/test[@id='0']");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Comment: But this will simply remove id="0", but not the row i select in my datagrid table?

Comment: this will remove the test node that has an id attribute of value 0.

Comment: Yes but the action should be performed deciding on what button i click on my buttoncolumn :) Also the .ParentNode does not appear. Regards.